# Why is the output of print("COMPUTER:"guess) not appearing on the console?

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python where you have to guess the number chosen by the computer. The number will be chosen between 0 and 10(inclusive of both the number). If the number guessed by the user is correct or wrong, a message will be shown based on the validity of the input (the number guessed by the user), followed by the number chosen by the computer as the outputs.
The output should be something like this.

```
ENTER: 4
Wrong
10 (Computer's choice)
```

**OR**

```
ENTER: 10
RIGHT!
10 (Computer's Choice)
```

**My Code:**

```
from random import randint
def guessing_game(x):
    guess = randint(0,10)
    if x.isdigit():
      if x==guess:
          return "RIGHT!"
          print(" COMPUTER =" guess)
      else:
          return "Wrong"
          print("COMPUTER="guess)
    elif x.isdigit() == False:
          return " Enter a Number"

print(guessing_game(input("ENTER:")))
```

The Problem is that the computer's `choice(Computer:10)` is not appearing on the console window.
The IDE on which I am making this program is telling me that *"CODE IS UNREACHABLE"*.
  THE ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
  ENTER:4
  Wrong
```

Hence, please help me to solve this issue. Every suggestion will be appreciated.

**THANK YOU**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your print is placed after a `return` instruction. That means at the execution in the case the user as found the guessed number, your function will return "RIGHT!" and **stop execution** of further code within this function.

That's why pycharm indicate that the code is unreachable

Comment: And btw, have a look on Patrick's answer below, he has also good advice (related to you code but not directly to the question)

Comment: You mean if I put "return"  first, the interpreter will only execute it and not the "print"  statement.

Comment: Yes exactly. You can test by putting your print before

Answer (score 0):

Your

> ```
> guess = randint(0,10)
> ```

is of type int.

Your

> ```
> print(guessing_game(input("ENTER:")))
> ```

is of type string.

This test

> ```
> if x==guess:
> ```

can never be `True`.

Beside that: `return` jumps out, nothing after it happes.

---

Use:

```
def guessing_game(x):
    guess = str(randint(0,10))  # make it a string
    if x==guess:                # compare two strings
        print(" COMPUTER =" guess)   # print first, then return. return jumps out!
        return "RIGHT!"
    else:
        print("COMPUTER="guess) 
        return "Wrong"
```

If the user inputs something other then a numnber, their problem.